# Customize return data from API to use in Datatable

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, api, datatable

I want to use datatable with the response from external API.
This is the result from api look like (I can't modify how the object response since it comes from the other resource):

```
{
"status": "success",
"code": "200",
"message": null,
"data": {
    "metadatas": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "totalPage": 7430,
        "totalRows": 74292,
        "links": {
            "currentLink": "/product/product?pagesize=10&pagenum=1",
            "nextLink": "/product/product?pagesize=10&pagenum=2",
            "previousLink": null,
            "firstLink": "/product/product?pagesize=10&pagenum=1",
            "lastLink": "/product/product?pagesize=10&pagenum=7430"
        }
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "no": 1,
            "productName": "P-1",
            "serial": "1000041"
        },
        {
            "no": 2,
            "productName": "P-2",
            "serial": "1000042"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

From what I have searched so far, look like we can use "dataSrc" to customize object return from serverside to meet DataTable requirement. I have tried to use it like this:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
 processing: true,
 serverSide: true,
 ajax: {
    url: baseAddress + 'product?pagesize=10&pagenum=1',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: searchCriteria,
    dataSrc: function (data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data); // Edited
        var json = {};
        json.data = data.data.products;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json)); // Got this result : {"data":[{"no":1,"productName":"P-1","serial":"1000041",....}]}
        return JSON.stringify(json);
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "no" },
        { "data": "productName" },
        { "data": "serial" }
      
    ]
    ]
 }
});
```

This is how my body object (`searchCriteria`that I send to API in order to get the result:

```
{
   "category":"All",
   "branch":"All",
   "userId" : "2"
}
```

And the result that I got in my table is:

[image]

With this alert error from datatable:

[image]

I kinda stuck in here, found no solution else on google.

Thank you in advanced.
Regard.

Comment: Pls post Api and searchCriteria.

Comment: @Serge : API result I already posted in my question `{"status": "success",...}` and for searchCriteria is just a body object that I have to passed to api. I will edit my question to add it :)

Comment: simply use `return json.data;` or `return json;` .

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the DataTable definition in your question cannot be the one you are actually using, because there are some structural and syntax problems in it:

- you have the `columns` option inside the `ajax` option, which is invalid.
- you have an extra `]` at the end of the DataTable definition.

If I correct those, I can display data by replacing all your `dataSrc` logic with this:

```
dataSrc: 'data.products'
```

This tells DataTables to look in the JSON received from the API and use the `data.products` locator to find where the row data array is located.

That is all you need to do to get your data to display in the table:

```js
$('#myTable').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: 'http://localhost:7001/products', // my test URL
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    //data: searchCriteria, // ignored for my test
    dataSrc: 'data.products'
  },
  columns: [
    { "data": "no" },
    { "data": "productName" },
    { "data": "serial" }
  ]
    
});
```

However, the problem with this is it does not handle summary information (shown underneath the DataTable):

```
Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)
```

It is awkward to correct this, because `serverSide` usually means you (a) have full control over the response structure, and (b) the server knows how to handle the automatically generated request sent by DataTables. In your case you do not have either of these things.

---

*Clarification*: By the "response structure" and the "automatically generated request", I mean the structures described in [this documentation page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).

The problem here is that `serverSide` is not really designed to be used with a 3rd party API over which you have no control.

---

Having said that, you can choose to handle this in different ways:

Hide the summary info using the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option:

```
dom: 'lfrtp',
```

Or, you can grab the `"totalRows": 74292` data from the JSON response and use it with the field names which DataTables is expecting to use. To do this, you need to use `dataSrc` with a function:

```js
$('#myTable').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: 'http://localhost:7001/products',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    //data: searchCriteria,
    //dataSrc: 'data.products' // replaced by the following...
    dataSrc: function (json) {
      var totalRows = json.data.metadatas.totalRows;
      json.recordsTotal = totalRows;
      json.recordsFiltered = totalRows;
      console.log( json );
      return json.data.products;
    }
  },
  columns: [
    { "data": "no" },
    { "data": "productName" },
    { "data": "serial" }
  ]
    
});
```

The `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` names are those I referred to earlier from [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data).

Now you will see a page similar to this:

[image]

---

This answer deliberately avoids issues related to pagination, sorting, and searching. Those are all typically handled by specific server-side code which is tied to the [request data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) automatically generated by DataTables.

You have some of that handled by `data: searchCriteria` - but that may need to be extended to fully support paging, sorting and searching (dependent on what the API provides for you, of course).

Comment: I follow `dataSrc` part that you suggested, my table this time is blank for all the rows. And datatable still alert the error : `DataTables warning: table id=tblLoanListTest - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`

Comment: Understood - that suggests there may be something else which is relevant, but not shown in the question. When I take your code and data, and make my modifications, I get the data displayed as expected.